# How to decode flac file on ios

Tags: ios, audio, mp3, flac

I am developing an iOS app that needs to play flac file. I used the AudioQueue to decode most of the music file, such as mp3 file. But it does not support flac file.

Does anyone know how to address this question?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this solutions works for you
https://github.com/ap4y/OrigamiEngine